# Getting a Facebook User Access Token without a login popup

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook SDK for .Net to get posts,likes and comments of a Facebook Page. That work's brilliantly.

However when I try to publish a post to the page - it fails on an oauth 2500 exception.

After some research I learnt I need to get extended permissions ("publish_stream") by confirming via a login pop up that I am an Admin on that Page.

That's all well.

However I am using a Service that does automated publishing of posts and images.

The service that I am using is Developed in VS2013 using C#.

Is there a way for getting a User Access Token to publish a post on a Page without a Login popup.

There are other articles that mention using a web browser control to login and intercepting the navigated event.

Other's mention using a HttpWebRequest.

These posts are fairly old - and I am wondering if there might be different techniques out there.

Comment: Do you need to post as a User, or as a Page?

Comment: I don't think you can post to a Page if you are using the API as far as I know - if you can that will be great. From what I read the User that created the page needs to be Admin on the Page which I am. The user needs to obtain the Access Token for the Page using their account "/me/accounts" - find the page get the access token.

Comment: This is what the documentation says - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: I know. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post to a page with an Page Access Token, as described in the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed/#publish

> A page access token with `publish_actions` permission can be used to
>   publish new posts on behalf of that page.

You can get the Page Access Token by issuing

```
GET /me/accounts
```

with the `publish_actions` permission (see docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/). Then, exchange the short-lived token to a long lived one:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending

Comment: Thanks for the answer and direction - but my question is to get to "/me/accounts" you would have to login via popup. The only way to get "/me/accounts" is to get a "User Access Token" Is there an automated way of bypassing the login.

Comment: Nope. This would be a big security hole, don't you think? Use the Graph Explorer for that: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v2.0

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. When you say use the Graph Explorer for that - what do you mean?